# How to 'echo' a Multi dimensional Array in Php?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the Array im working with

```
[container:protected] => Array
  (
   [campaigns] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
      (
       [id] => 1
        [name] => Merry Christmas
        [type] => classic
        [status] => draft
        [sender] => stdClass Object
        (
         [name] => Prebic
         [id] => 1
         [email] => prebic@balworld.in
         ))
    [count] => 1
    )
)
```

and Printing the Same in HTML Table using

```
<?php foreach($result['campaigns'] as $bw_campaigns): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $bw_campaigns['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $bw_campaigns['type'] ?></td>
<tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can i print the value inside [sender] array ?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<td><?php echo $bw_campaigns['sender']->name ?></td>
<td><?php echo $bw_campaigns['sender']->id ?></td>
<td><?php echo $bw_campaigns['sender']->email ?></td>
```

And sender is not an array, is an object.

Answer (score -1):

Noticing that the `sender` is actually `stdClass`, its members should be accessed with the following syntax:

```
$obj->member
```

Therefore, to get the value in sender, just do

```
<td><?php echo $bw_campaigns['sender']->name ?></td>
...
```